# PHP: Create Variables with content out of an array - in a loop

Tags: php, arrays, loops, for-loop

I've got an simple array and I want to save each entry of it to an own variable.

My array `$cars = array("bmw", "mercedes");` 
With this I know how many entries exist in the array: `$count = count($cars);`

Than I tried the following code:

```
for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
{
    $car+1 = $cars[$i];
}
```

But this does not work.

I want a result like this:

```
$car1 = bmw
$car2 = mercedes
```

So the loop should create the variables automatically, the name is "car" and the respective number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$cars = array("bmw", "mercedes");
$count = count($cars);

for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
{
    $variableName = 'car'.($i + 1);
    $$variableName = $cars[$i];
}

echo $car1.' '.$car2;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?
$cars = array("bmw", "mercedes");

$count = count($cars);
$j=1;
for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
{
    $TotalCars='$car'.$j.'=';
    echo $TotalCars. $cars[$i]."<br>";
    $j++;
}
?>
```

**Output:**
[image]

Comment: This loop does not produce several variables, I'm sorry this does not work for my purpose

Comment: After posting this answer. I modified it. Please check once more time. It will work @coder

Comment: I'm sorry it just produces a $TotalCars variable and not an own variable for each car name.

Comment: Hi @coder. I have made correction to it. Now, its working fine. I checked personally. Have a look into it, if you didn't got any answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

```
for($i = 1; $i <= count($cars); $i++)
{
    $car = 'car' . $i;
    $$car = $cars[$i-1];
    print $$car .PHP_EOL; // print inside the loop
}
```

and printintg outside the loop

```
print $car1 . PHP_EOL;
print $car2 . PHP_EOL;
```